# SharePoint2013 On-prem retrieve user profile data plugin using REST

Tags: jquery, json, rest, sharepoint

I've been creating an app for SharePoint2013 on-prem that allows me to retrieve users name and siplay it using REST api and jQuery. I tested it on O365 and it worked just fine, but I'm getting an error on-prem where I'm telling it the dataType to return is json however it keeps returning xml. I think as a solution I'd have to try and parse xml into json but this is just an uneducated guess. Code Provided below.

userinfo file

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getCurrentUserProfile");

var CurrentUserInformation;
var subscribeUserData = [];

function getCurrentUserProfile() {
    var userInfo = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata"
        },
        complete: function(data) {
        CurrentUserInformation = data;
        SP.SOD.notifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("userinfo.js");
        }
    });
}
```

displaydata file

```
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {

//creates the default data
var pluginName = "DisplayUserData",
    defaults = {
        user: null
        };

//plugin ctor
function DisplayUserData(element, options) {
    var that = this;

    that.element = element;
    that.$element = jQuery(element);

    that.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    that.defaults = defaults;

    that.styleLibraryPath = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/SiteAssets/userdata/displaydata";

    that.init();
}

DisplayUserData.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        var that = this;


        if(typeof that.options.user != null) {
            var templateCall = that.getTemplate(that.options.template);

            templateCall.complete(function (data) {
                that.mix(data);
                });
            }
        },

    getTemplate: function (template) {
        var that = this;
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: that.styleLibraryPath +"/" + template,
            type: "GET",
            cache: true,
            data: {},
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: "text/html"
            });
        },

    mix: function (data) {
        var that = this,
            template = data,
            results = that.getValueByKey(that.options.property, that.options.user);
        if (results !== "" && typeof results != 'undefined') {
            that.display(results, template);
            }
        },

    getValueByKey: function (key, obj) {
    var data = jQuery.grep(obj.UserProfileProperties, function (item) {
    return item.Key == key;
    });

    if (data.length > 0) {
        var value = data[0].Value;
        if (key === "Title") {
            var titleSegments = value.split(" ");
            value = titleSegments[titleSegments.length - 1];
            }
            return value;
        }
    },

    display: function (results, template) {
        var that = this;
        var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
        var outputHtml = compiledTemplate(results);
        that.$element.html(outputHtml);
        }
    };

    //plugin wrapper prventing multiple instantiations

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
        new DisplayUserData(this, options));
        });
    };
}) (jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it occurs since `application/json;odata=nometadata` Accept header is not supported in your environment. Microsoft [introduced JSON Light support in REST SharePoint API](https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/) after SharePoint 2013 has been released.

Having said that you could consider the following options to return results in JSON format:

**Option 1**

If you have SharePoint Server 2013 **with** Service Pack 1 (SP1) installed, then follow [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn762092(v=office.15).aspx) in order to to turn on and off the multiple metadata formats for the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) feature in a SharePoint Server 2013 environment.

**Option 2**

If you have SharePoint Server 2013 **without** Service Pack 1 (SP1) installed, then change `Accept` header from `application/json;odata=nometadata` to `application/json;odata=verbose`, for example:

```
function getMyProperties(){
    var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";
    return $.ajax({       
       url: requestUrl,   
       type: "GET",  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
    });
}


//Usage
getMyProperties()
.done(function(data)
{
     var properties = data.d;
     console.log(properties);
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I couldn't support JSON light, (i secretly blame the admin who set up the environment :P) Thanks for the answer and the detail :)